# Cassandra vs HDFS to store analytics data

Tags: performance, apache-spark, cassandra, hdfs

we have an Apache Spark cluster that analyse data stored in HDFS (.parquet). 
The solution is optimal in terms of performance but it's not disaster safe as we would like, indeed, HDFS architecture has a single point of failure (the namenode) even using two namenode (you just have 2 point of failure but it's not enough).
To improve our cluster fault tolerance we would like to move to another data store solution like Cassandra. 
Questions are:

- With Cassandra as datastore is Spark able to leverage on DataLocality as it do with HDFS?
- How this change can affect the performance?

Thanks

Matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's article about data locality, spark and Cassandra, so yes, it is possible:

https://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/cassandra-and-spark-optimizing-russell-spitzer-1

I didn't done any performance checks with Spark on HDFS vs Cassandra, and i believe it will vary depending on different workflows, but since Netflix and Microsoft using Cassandra with Spark, i believe performance is acceptable in most cases, and probably is a trade-off between data ingestion speed, existence/nonexistence of ETL and speed of the analytical process.

About hadoop single point of failure - If you will run Cassandra with replication factor 3 and consistency level quorum, you will get same 2 nodes down that will make data unavailable :) , keep it in mind.

And maybe consider MapR hadoop distribution, they've tried to solve namenode problem.

Comment: Thanks, we have at least 30 nodes so, with a consistency level quorum we should have 16 replica of the same data. I will dig into the document you shared. Thanks!

Comment: That's not how it works :) You can have 100 nodes, but only 3 replicas of same data on them, and quorum will be 2 out of 3. You can go higher than 3, but there's no reason to go to 30.